# Ember cli using coffeescript in express server files

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli and I generated some server files with:

```
ember g http-mock contacts
```

so I have an index.js and a contacts.js. Is there any way to use coffescript in these files without diving into the ember cli core files? I have tried converting everything numerous times but no luck. I am using coffescript in my main app with the ember-cli node module and it works great so I would think it shouldn't be this difficult to make it work in the server folder as well. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: "shouldn't be" give it a try and PR it :)

Comment: You *may* be able to do it by just `npm install`ing coffeescript and the requiring the register at the top of your .coffee files in the mock

Comment: Thanks @Constarr I will try that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I never found one. I actually started using Meteor instead of Ember so that kind of solved my problem in a different way I guess.